# Using Javascript to Post data to a processing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to post data to a processing php page in the background. After the JavaScript runs, I run some PHP which shouldn't be a problem.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: 'https://processingsiteurl.com/register2.php',
            type: 'POST', // GET or POST
            data: 'f_refer_by="129"&sinup_id="2"&sinup_z_First_Name_="Rossontf1"&sinup_z_Last_Name_="Ras4z123a"&sinup_z_Email_="6s11albertoramirez@armyangel.com"&sinup_z_Choose_Password_="abc123"&sinup_z_Confirm_Password_="abc123"&sinup_z_Fundraiser_Display_Name="Test123"&sinup_z_Fundraiser_Dates="Test123"&sinup_z_Members_in_Organization="73"&sinup_z_Email_Format_="1"&sinup_z_Name_of_Campaign="Test123".val()', // will be in $_POST on PHP side
            success: function(data) { // data is the response from your php script
                // This function is called if your AJAX query was successful
                alert("Response is: " + data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
                alert("Error!" + data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is I'm getting an "[object Object]" error. and then the script dies.

Comment: `alert(arguments[2])` and check the console for errors.

Comment: Where is `[object Object]` appearing - in the alert from the error callback?  Try `console.log(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","https://processingsiteurl.com/register2.php",false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("f_refer_by=129&sinup_id=2.......other parameters.....");
```

Comment: @user3018854 try with few simple parameters. Maybe problem is in proper encoding or double quotes...

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your ajax data and put it in an object, not a string; you're making life too hard on yourself.  Example:

```
// Everything before data goes here
        data: {
            "f_refer_by": "129",
            "sinup_id": "2",
            "sinup_z_First_Name_": "Rossontf1",
            "sinup_z_Last_Name_": "Ras4z123a",
            "sinup_z_Email_": "6s11albertoramirez@armyangel.com",
            "sinup_z_Choose_Password_": "abc123",
            "sinup_z_Confirm_Password_": "abc123",
            "sinup_z_Fundraiser_Display_Name": "Test123",
            "sinup_z_Fundraiser_Dates": "Test123",
            "sinup_z_Members_in_Organization": "73",
            "sinup_z_Email_Format_": "1",
            "sinup_z_Name_of_Campaign": '"Test123".val()' // will be in $_POST on PHP side
        },
// Everything after data goes here
```

Also, you have a value containing `"Test123".val()`.  I doubt this is what you want. It sounds like you probably mean something like `$('#Test123').val()`, but I can't tell.

Comment: Hi Ed,  Thank you for your answer... I used your suggestion, but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: What is the response your PHP script is returning? If your script is returning, say, JSON data, jQuery may be flipping out when you alert something `+ data`.